# Apex Trigger to create a Cross- Object Rollup Field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a custom Object called `Application__c` that has a lookup relationship to the `Opportunity` object. I have a field called `total_applications__c` on the `Opportunity` which aims to represent the total number of applications related to that opportunity.

I trying to populate that field though an apex trigger on the `Application__c` object that operates on `after insert, after delete and after undelete` events.

Considering the insert event :

My initial approach is that each time an application is being inserted I

-> create an oppset with all the opportunities that are being linked to from the applications that have been triggered

-> loop through all the applications that are link to an opportunity from the oppset

-> add the number of applications related to each opportunity in a map

-> loop though all the related opportunities from the applications that have currently being inserted

-> update that total_applications__c field with the computed values from the map.

However I feel that I can achieve the same functionality in fewer steps. Is there a better way of achieving what I described above?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) for this purpose. You would then create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` something like:

- Parent Object: `Opportunity`
- Relationship Field: `Opportunity__c`
- Child Object: `Application__c`
- Field to Aggregate: `Id`
- Aggregate Operation: `Count`
- Aggregate Result Field: `Total_Applications__c`

Clicks not code!

Comment: thanks for your answer but I would prefer an inhouse solution rather than relying on a 3rd party implementation.  And my example stated above is just a simplified version of the actual business application.

Comment: Rejecting all pre-built solutions out of hand seems somewhat obtuse. DLRS can certainly handle a lot more complexity than I have outlined here.